# Two Android Activities beside each other similar to snapchat

Tags: android, navigation, swipe, snapchat

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to create a similar UI to Snapchat. Where you have two or three activities beside each other and you can swipe between them or press a button to switch activity. How would I go about doing this?

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: have a look at Android fragments.

Comment: "Where you have two or three activities beside each other and you can swipe between them" -- those are not activities. "How would I go about doing this?" -- use a `ViewPager`.

Comment: or a tabbed activity

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot guys for the help!

Comment: @timmyman123 how did you do it can you please tell me ?

Answer (score 0):

They are not activities.. they are fragments tied by ViewPager.

This library may help you to get started

[SnapTabLayout library replicating Snapchat Bottom UI](https://github.com/nirukk52/SnapTabLayout)